# Converter uma variável para um reflect.Type

Tags: cast, golang

Comecei a aprender Go recentemente. Quero poder salvar um tipo de dado em uma variável, e converter outra variável para ele. Sei que uma forma de salvar um tipo de dado é usando `reflect.Type`.

```
i := 5
t := reflect.TypeOf(i)
var f float32 = 4.2
```

Mas como faço para converter `f` para o tipo salvo em `t`?

Comment: Você realmente precisa usar o pacote reflect ou você quer fazer apenas uma simples conversão de tipos? Isso não seria suficiente? https://go-tour-br.appspot.com/basics/13

Comment: @navossoc A ideia é converter para um tipo dinamicamente, que estará salvo na classe

Comment: Veja se seria algo assim: https://goplay.space/#MxUau0Dbmq
De qualquer maneira, não entendi ainda onde você quer chegar.